# match cols a and c then match cols b and d

Tags: excel, match

I'm trying to match cols a(id) and c(id), then the corresponding ''balance'' columns b(balance) and d(balance).

e.g. i need output like that in e(does balance match keying on id):

```
id  balance id  balance does balance match keying on id
1   20.1    2   30  yes
2   30  6   24.6    no
3   12.5    4   16  yes
4   16  5   51  no
5   50  3   12.5    yes
6   24.5    1   20.1    yes
```

It's driving me nuts.  I can match id with vlookup, but if the rows are all mixed up (as above) i can't easily compare the corresponding balances in b and d.  If the rows where in order it would be easy of course (use an IF(b = d, "true","false"))
I have literally tens of thousands of rows in this condition.

Does anyone know a way to do this?  Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: is just sorting columns c and d by id descending not an option?

Answer (score 1):

Use Array formulas...

Put this in E1:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2&D2,A:A&B:B,0))
```

Then hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter to make it an array formula and drag down

Hope this does the trick!!

Comment: ... Also, to make it more efficient, you can change "A:A" to a more specific range such as "A2:A1000" and the same for "B:B"

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `vlookup` here unless I am not understanding something completely.  If your headings are in row 1 and values start in row 2, that puts your values over the range A2 to D(x) where x is your last row of values.  In your example above this would be row 7, so A2 to D7.

You can set your 'balance match' (E2 in your example) to use this formula, again substituting 7 for x in $D$x to define the range of your data set.

```
=IF(D2=VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$D$7,2),"yes", "no")
```

Then drag that to the last row to complete the result column.

Comment: Truth is I kinda like Adam's answer more than mine - I try and avoid array formulas if I have the option... Nice and efficient, Adam

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

Assuming your data starts in A1...

Formula for E2 could be

```
=IF(INDEX(A:D,MATCH(C2,A:A),2)=D2,"Yes","No")
```

Copy and pasting of this formula down all rows will give the results requested.

Note that I am using A:D so that you do not need to define the range of your data only the columns.